# Grafana not showing metrics shown by springboot prometheus endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, grafana

I have configured micrometer and prometheus for my spring boot application, and I can see following metrics(genrated using Timer) at endpoint /actuator/prometheus:

```
# HELP timer_test_seconds Time spent serving test requests
# TYPE timer_test_seconds summary
timer_test_seconds_count{class="com.test.MyController",exception="none",method="testTimer",} 2.0
timer_test_seconds_sum{class="com.test.MyController",exception="none",method="testTimer",} 8.6461705
# HELP timer_test_seconds_max Time spent serving test requests
# TYPE timer_test_seconds_max gauge
timer_test_seconds_max{class="com.test.MyController",exception="none",method="testTimer",} 4.5578234
```

But when I run one of this query in Grafana(configured against prometheus instance), I don't see any result.

Is any configuration needed for this?

Answer (score 0):

These are the metrics exposed by your service. Grafana does not interact with your service directly.

1. Is Prometheus up and scraping this target? You can check if Prometheus has any data at localhost:port/graph.
2. Is Grafana pointing to your Prometheus endpoint correctly?

Most likely, Prometheus is not scraping your target correctly. Keep in mind that Grafana is unaware of your service at all so you should first check if there is any data in Prometheus.